# Cannot clone over SSH from GitHub with key generated by phpseclib

Tags: laravel, git, ssh, rsa, phpseclib

I am working on feature that allows users to clone from any git service provider using SSH.
We create the SSH key pair using the phpseclib package inside of a Laravel app. We then store the private key and ask the user to add the public key to their git account on whatever service they use. The user can then enter the git@url to clone their repo. 
However, I get an error that 'Host key verification failed' when attempting to clone a private repo from GitHub.

Code for creating the SSH key pair:

```php
$rsa = new RSA();

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(RSA::PRIVATE_FORMAT_OPENSSH:);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH);
$rsa->setComment(auth()->user()->email);

$key = $rsa->createKey(4096);

// Then save $key['privatekey']
```

Do I need to save the private key and public key onto the server too?

Anyone got any ideas on the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: *...I get an error that 'Host key verification failed...* You get the error from what, and where? Certainly not from the code you put in your question.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk The application runs shell scripts using Laravel's blade templating engine to pass in variables and allows me to see an output of the shell script. That output contains the 'Host key verification failed' error.

Comment: There are two authentications that occur in SSH: 1) the client authenticates the server, and 2) the server authenticates the client. Your code is managing #2 but there error you see is about #1. You need to put the server's key in the clients 'known_hosts' file, or something equivalent.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I have added the private key to the server and added the public key to my GitHub account which in theory should allow me to clone my own private repo to the server. However, I get the error I listed. My thoughts were that it was an error in the key pair creation, but to be honest I have no idea.

Comment: Don't confuse the issue by being careless with words like "the server". There are servers and clients everywhere. Be as specific as possible. We are talking about the *SSH server*, which in this case is github, and we are talking about the *SSH client*, which you apparently run via a shell script. Your SSH client must have already trusted github's SSH public key prior to making a connection. At least for the openssh command line client I am familiar with those SSH server public keys are placed in ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: Can you connect to the server that's hosting the Laravel app and do `git clone` via the command line there? If so what is the response that you get?